# C++ Decrypting Base64 string in ASCII using OpenSSL AES_128_CBC

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I have a encrypted string in base64 as ASCII string (std::string) and a key as ASCII string. The iv will just be empty. The key will be variable length and will use padding (and I still don't know how to do this yet). I would like to use OpenSSL AES 128 CBC to decrypt that to the original text. I'm using the source code from the wiki. However the result I got are just random character when I cout or print with %s. Here is the source code:

```
int main(void)
{

unsigned char* key = (unsigned char*)"okamura";


unsigned char* iv = (unsigned char*)"";

unsigned char* base64 = (unsigned char*)"BPaHjjva7bBjrDQrJyekPA==";

/*
 * Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the
 * ciphertext which may be longer than the plaintext, depending on the
 * algorithm and mode.
 */
unsigned char ciphertext[128];

/* Buffer for the decrypted text */
unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

/* Decrypt the ciphertext */
decryptedtext_len = decrypt(base64, sizeof(base64), key, iv,
    decryptedtext);

/* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

/* Show the decrypted text */
printf("Decrypted text is:\n");
printf("%s", decryptedtext);
return 0;
}
```

Decrypt function

```
int decrypt(unsigned char* ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char* key,
unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* plaintext)
{
EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx;

int len;

int plaintext_len;

/* Create and initialise the context */
if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
{

}
    //handleErrors();

/*
 * Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
 * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
 * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
 * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
 * is 128 bits
 */
if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
{

}
    //handleErrors();

/*
 * Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
 * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary.
 */
if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
{

}
    //handleErrors();
plaintext_len = len;

/*
 * Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
 * this stage.
 */
if (1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len))
{

}
    //handleErrors();
plaintext_len += len;

/* Clean up */
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

return plaintext_len;
}
```

Encrypt function

```
int encrypt(unsigned char* plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char* key,
unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* ciphertext)
{
EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx;

int len;

int ciphertext_len;

/* Create and initialise the context */
if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
    handleErrors();

/*
 * Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
 * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
 * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
 * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
 * is 128 bits
 */
if (1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
    handleErrors();

/*
 * Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
 * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
 */
if (1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
    handleErrors();
ciphertext_len = len;

/*
 * Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
 * this stage.
 */
if (1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len))
    handleErrors();
ciphertext_len += len;

/* Clean up */
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

return ciphertext_len;
}
```

Comment: CBC uses an IV. If you don't have an IV, your data is incomplete. But maybe the IV is concatenated with the ciphertext or is a zero IV. If you don't have more detailed information about the encryption, only guesses can be made. It would be most helpful if you post the encryption code.

Comment: Since both data and code are unreliable, I would recommend using reliable data to evaluate the code and a reliable tool/code to evaluate the data. Otherwise, if there is a problem, you will never know for sure if it is the data or the code.

Comment: I don't use the encryption code to decrypt. What I have are the password, the encrypted string in base64, that's all. I used an online tool to decrypt the string and I got the correct string back. The tool only requires password.
I also made a similar decryption tool in Csharp using System.Cryptography. I put in empty iv and still have the original string back.

Comment: This is the online tool I used: https://encode-decode.com/aes-128-cbc-encrypt-online/

Comment: AES-128 applies a 16 bytes key. Your key `okamura` is only 7 bytes long. CBC uses a 16 bytes IV, you don't specify an IV at all. The web site you use is not very good, because it silently pads the key with 0x00 values to 16 bytes and takes a zero vector as IV.

Comment: A prerequisite for the decryption with the C/C++ code is that the correct values for key and IV (and ciphertext) are applied.

Comment: As I said, I will pad the key with 0x00 to reach the reqruied length. All I need now is what data type do I need to feed the decrypt function. I'll edit my question with the encrypt function as well.

Comment: No idea what you mean by _data type_. Your C/C++ `decrypt()` method does not perform Base64 decoding. If you want to decrypt the Base64 encoded ciphertext `BPaH...` you still have to add this functionality, or alternatively pass the Base64 decoded data, e.g. `unsigned char base64[] = { 0x04, 0xf6, 0x87,...};`

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need. Now I know that I need to feed the decrypt function decoded data as hex like you said.
However, how do I convert a string, or unsigned char *, in plain ASCII above, to an array of unsigned char hex decoded from base64 similar to yours?